# Hacking the social [Combinatorics]

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> In a social network with a fixed finite setback of users, each user
>   had a fixed set of followers among the other users. Each user has an
>   initial positive integer rating (not necessarily the same for all
>   users). Every midnight, the rating of every user increases by the sum
>   of the ratings that his followers had just before midnight. Let $m$ be
>   a positive integer. A hacker, who is not a user of the social network,
>   wants all the users to have ratings divisible by $m$. Every day, he
>   can either choose a user and increase his rating by 1, or do nothing.
>   Prove that the hacker can achieve his goal after some number of days.

**Solution:** Number the persons $1$ through $n$ and consider the $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix given by $A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ with $a_{ij}=1$ if $j$ follows $i$ and $0$ otherwise.
The main observation is that if in midnight the column vector given by the user's rating is $x$, the next midnight it will be $Ax.$
Let $e_i\in\mathcal{M}_{n,1}$ be the column vector with $1$ in position $i$ and $0$ in all other positions.
The hacker can add one $e_i$ to $x$ at midnight, or can do nothing.
Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be the initial user's ratings reduced modulo $m$ and $b_i=m-a_i$ for each $i$.
By PHP, there are distinct numbers $p>c_1>c_2>...>c_{b_1+...+b_n}$ such that $A^p\equiv A^{c_j}(\text{mod}~m)$ for any $j$. Then$$(a_i\cdot A^p+A^{c_{b_1+...+b_{i-1}+1}}+....+A^{c_{b_1+....+b_i}})e_i\equiv 0(\text{mod}~m)$$for each $i=\overline{1,n}.$

Thus the hacker can add $e_i$ in midnights $p-c_{b_1+...+b_{i-1}+1},...,p-c_{b_1+....+b_i}$ for each $i$, and by the above it can easily be seen to be enough, since the resulting vector would be$$A^px+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(A^{c_{b_1+...+b_{i-1}+1}}+....+A^{c_{b_1+....+b_i}})e_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i\cdot A^p+A^{c_{b_1+...+b_{i-1}+1}}+....+A^{c_{b_1+....+b_i}})e_i\equiv 0(\text{mod}~m).$$ Q.E.D

So is there a new solution?

Comment: A social network with a "setback" of users. Hmmmm. Is that commentary?

Comment: Per your question, a proof without linear algebra would look like a royal mess, and would simply be doing linear algebra in disguise. Linear algebra is the obvious clean way to approach this. You might find a proof without using PHP, but it would still be stated in linear algebra to be readable.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So is there a new solution?

Comment: What does PHP mean here? Presumably an acronym for something. Looks like something related to the Chinese remainder theorem, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: PigeonHole Principle